# PHP bind_param and Decimal values not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a PHP script to store some values in MySql table.

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `KeyPad` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `phone1` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 `concept1` double(11,4) NOT NULL,
 `phone2` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 `concept2` double(11,4) NOT NULL,
 `phone3` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 `concept3` double(11,4) NOT NULL,
 `phone4` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 `concept4` decimal(11,4) NOT NULL,
 `phone5` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 `concept5` double(11,4) NOT NULL,
 `phone6` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 `concept6` double(11,4) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

My PHP scripts are like this:

Config.php:

```
<?php
define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_HOST', 'hostname');
define('DB_NAME', 'DB_name');
```

DbConnect.php:

```
<?php

class DbConnect
{
    private $conn;

    function __construct()
    {
    }
    function connect()
    {
        require_once 'config.php';
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        // Check for database connection error
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        // returing connection resource
        return $this->conn;
    }
```

DbOperation.php:

```
<?php

class DbOperation
{
    private $conn;

    //Constructor
    function __construct()
    {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Config.php';
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
        // opening db connection
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    //Function to create a new user
    public function createentry($P1, $C1, $P2, $C2, $P3, $C3, $P4, $C4, $P5, $C5, $P6, $C6)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO KeyPad(phone1, concept1, phone2, concept2, phone3, concept3, phone4, concept4, phone5, concept5, phone6, concept6) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("idididididid", $P1, $C1, $P2, $C2, $P3, $C3, $P4, $C4, $P5, $C5, $P6, $C6);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        if ($result) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Lastly, createentry.php:

```
<?php

//creating response array
$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //getting values
    $ph1 = $_POST['phone1'];
    $co1 = $_POST['concept1'];
    $ph2 = $_POST['phone2'];
    $co2 = $_POST['concept2'];
    $ph3 = $_POST['phone3'];
    $co3 = $_POST['concept3'];
    $ph4 = $_POST['phone4'];
    $co4 = $_POST['concept4'];
    $ph5 = $_POST['phone5'];
    $co5 = $_POST['concept5'];
    $ph6 = $_POST['phone6'];
    $co6 = $_POST['concept6'];

    //including the db operation file
    require_once '../includes/DbOperation.php';

    $db = new DbOperation();

    //inserting values
    if($db->createentry($ph1, $co1, $ph2, $co2, $ph3, $co3, $ph4, $co4, $ph5, $co5, $ph6, $co6)){
        $response['error']=false;
        $response['message']='Team added successfully';
    }else{

        $response['error']=true;
        $response['message']='Could not add team';
    }

}else{
    $response['error']=true;
    $response['message']='You are not authorized';
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

I am not sure if the part where i am doing:

```
$stmt->bind_param("idididididid",
```

is correct or not. Because, when I run this on postman, i get an error saying:

```
"error":true,"message":"Could not add team"
```

Comment: For phone1/2/3/4/5/6 i am expecting a 10 digit number and for Concept1/2/3/4/5/6 i am expecting decimal numbers like 10.345 or 2.11 or 3.56 etc.

Comment: try to find-out real error produce by `mysqli`, don't dependent on your own error message

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: This schema is also a pretty flagrant violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you write the output of this SQL query in a variable and log it.
Then you can execute it on your favorite MySQL client see what the error is.
in your DbOperation.php, add this :

```
$log = "INSERT INTO KeyPad(phone1, concept1, phone2, concept2, phone3, concept3, phone4, concept4, phone5, concept5, phone6, concept6) values($P1, $C1, $P2, $C2, $P3, $C3, $P4, $C4, $P5, $C5, $P6, $C6);";
error_log($log, 3, "/path/to/your/error.log");
```

Run your script and then the log will contain the request you can run manually.
That way you will be able to see what the db is complaining about.

Comment: Ok Great, I tried to log the MySqli error and I got this: "Column 'phone1' cannot be null" Even when I have passed values for each required field via a post request.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I realised that I was sending the parameters from Postman whereas I needed to send them via "body".